# How to render view if validation failed? (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller

devs!

What I have:

I have link to a new action dishes controller, with passing parameter day_id. Look like this:

```
<%= link_to "Add new dish", new_dish_path(id: @day) %>
```

**I have a controller (dishes controller)**

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController  
  def new 
    @dish = Dish.new 
    @dish.courses.build 
    @day = Day.find(params[:id])
   end

    def create
     @dish = Dish.new(dish_params) 
    if @dish.save
       redirect_to '/dashboard' 
    else 
      render :new
     end 
  end

    private def dish_params 
    params.require(:dish).permit(:id, :name, :description, :price, :course_name, courses_attributes: [:day_id]) 
  end  
end
```

**I have a view:**

```
<div class="new dish">
   <%= form_for @dish do |d|  %>
     <% if @dish.errors.any? %> 
      <% @dish.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></div>
       <% end %>
     <% end %> 
  <%= d.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Dish name" %>
   <%= d.text_area :description, :placeholder => "Description" %> 
  <%= d.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Dish price" %>
   <%= d.text_field :course_name, :placeholder => "Course name" %> 
  <%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %>
       <%= c.hidden_field :day_id, value: @day.id %> 
  <%= d.submit "Save" %> 
</div>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

When I click link “Add new dish” the url looks like this ( id=1 – this is day id which may change depending on from what day I click on the link):

```
http://localhost:3000/dishes/new?id=1
```

If I fill all fields in form (see view above) - **everything will be fine**. A new dish and a new course create.

**What is the problem?**

I add simple validation for 1 field in model Dish:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :courses 
  has_many :days, through: :courses
   has_many :order_items
   validates :course_name, presence: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses
 end
```

And now when I don’t fill fields and click “Save” instead of getting a validation error shown in the view i get an error like: (log)

```
Started POST "/dishes" for ::1 at 2020-10-23 13:31:43 +0300
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by DishesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"HfFhXKjv3ldt7vpL3HNDO/udECSItssnMT4tWf9SXaRyejW6+Jd35Vci16ZTSE1ZM0D+0Eain6CJ1DhOZxPgXA==", "dish"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "price"=>"", "course_name"=>"", "courses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"day_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Day Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days" WHERE "days"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Rendering dishes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered dishes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.0ms | Allocations: 1765)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 6650)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
    10:   <%= d.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Dish price" %>
    11:   <%= d.text_field :course_name, :placeholder => "Course name" %>
    12:   <%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %>
    13:       <%= c.hidden_field :day_id, value: @day.id %>
    14:   <%= d.submit "Save" %>
    15: </div>
    16: <% end %>
  
app/views/dishes/new.html.erb:13
app/views/dishes/new.html.erb:12
app/views/dishes/new.html.erb:2
app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

I think the error occurs because the id of the day is lost when trying to render view if validation failed (see the create controller action). May you help me and tell how to work around this behavior or tell the best practices how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by introducing a global variable.

**In DishesController instead of:**

```
@day = Day.find(params[:id])
```

i changed the variable to global:

```
$day = Day.find(params[:id])
```

**then in view instead of:**

```
<%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %>
       <%= c.hidden_field :day_id, value: @day.id %>
```

i also changed the variable to global:

```
<%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %>
       <%= c.hidden_field :day_id, value: $day.id %>
```

The rest of the code remained unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

All the setup you do in `new` that is required for the view should also be done just before `render :new`. `render :new` renders the view immediately without calling `new`, which is expected because you don't want `@dish = Dish.new`  to override your `@dish` with all the errors do you?

Either duplicate the setup, move it to a shared method and call it or make your view less dependent on the controller.

```
def create
  @dish = Dish.new(dish_params) 
  if @dish.save
    redirect_to '/dashboard' 
  else
    @dish.courses.build  # if not already built by new/save
    @day = Day.find(params[:id]) 
    render :new
  end 
end
```

For your specific case you could also move `@day = ...` to a `before_action`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, @Siim Liiser. Slowly I understand what you said. But if in the controller I do as you said.
def create
  @dish = Dish. new (dish_params)
  if @ dish.save
    redirect_to '/dashboard'
  else
    @dish.courses.build
    @day = Day.find (params [:id])
    render :new
  end
end
I am getting the error:
Completed 404, not found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 5965)
ActiveRecord :: RecordNotFound (Couldn't find day without id):
  
app / controllers / dishes_controller.rb: 15: in `create '

Comment: @day = Day.find(params[:day_id])

Comment: @roshiend, hello! There is no param like day_id in model Day. day_id it's courses_attributes, column in courses table.

Comment: try change `<%= d.fields_for :courses do |c| %>` to `<%= d.fields_for :courses, Course.new  do |c| %>`

Comment: @roshiend, the same error. ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Day without an ID)

Comment: Have u added belong to in ur model ?.

Comment: @roshiend, hello! Yes in model Course i have belongs_to :day belongs_to :dish In model Day i have has_many :courses has_many :dishes, through: :courses has_many :order_items